# CNN training multi label classification---not working

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Try to predict texture images' labels, an image can contain two labels like['banded', 'striped'], though most of them only have one label.

The output accuracy is extremely high....the first epoch can have 0.96 acc...but the prediction array are all close to 0, which is wrong, there must be at least one number is relevant closed to 1.

Can someone help me?
Thank you!!

Here are the code

```
Input image = (read by opencv)/255
Multi-labels = First LabelEncoder convert to numbers, then keras.to_categorical
```

Then I built a CNN model as follow

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(img_array, test_value, test_size=0.1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='Same', data_format='channels_last', activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(300, 300, 3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='Same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(300, init ='uniform',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(285, init = 'uniform',activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size= 24, epochs=10, validation_split=0.15)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model has only 2 labels, the last layer should be

`model.add(Dense(2, init = 'uniform',activation='sigmoid'))`

However, your class imbalance can also affect the accuracy. If your class imbalance is too high, your model will show 95%+ training, validation, and testing accuracies but the individual accuracies will still be low and the model will not work for real world data.

The detailed and class-based accuracy can be understood using :

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report



X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.30)
X_test1, X_valid, y_test1, y_valid = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size=0.30)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=8, shuffle=True, validation_data=(X_test1,y_test1), callbacks=[metrics])

Y_TEST = np.argmax(y_valid, axis=1)
y_pred = model.predict_classes(X_valid)

print("#"*50,"\n",classification_report(Y_TEST, y_pred))
```

Please share your class distribution for further understanding.

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain this well. This data set has 47 categories, each image has a main category,  and plus some of them have multi-label.

Comment: Do the two categories fall in the set of 47 categories? If yes, then when you are predicting the values, try `y_pred = model.predict(X_valid)` and then print the two  indices with the maximum values (out of the 47), and set the probability threshold for the 2nd category for its acceptance.

Comment: Hello, I'm confused, each class has the same number of images, just the number of labels of images is an imbalance? All the images have their own main category, just several of them have 2 or more categories. Mmmmm, multi-class, multi-label.....           Im using this dataset :https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/dtd/  ....      BTW I keep having this error on your code "Mix type of y not allowed, got types {'multiclass', 'continuous-multioutput'}"......though I've converted their type to float32....what a frustrated.....

Comment: OK I change something, it has the same result as mine....  avg / total       0.00      0.00      0.00       508

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the number of neurons in Dense layer is 285. If there are 47 categories, then the output neurons of Dense layer should be 47. Also, use a kernel initializer like he_normal instead of uniform. https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/resnet50.py

```
model.add(Dense(47, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is a multi-label classification example with 5 classes.

https://github.com/suraj-deshmukh/Keras-Multi-Label-Image-Classification

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I will check the two examples now.   285 is the total label after K-hot-encoder, as I mentioned before, for example, though image A belongs to category"banded" which is its main label, it is also classified to "striped" category, therefore it has two labels. So the total labels are not 74, they're 285.  However.....I've tried to predict just use the first label of each image....also has same problem....

Comment: No, if there are 47 categories, there should be only 47 outputs. That is why we use sigmoid activation. If an image belongs to one category, say 2, y_true =[0, 0, 1, ...0] . If an image belongs to more than one category, say 1 & 5, then y_true = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,...0]. This way the sigmoid activations of those outputs will be trained to be high values.

Comment: Ah! right! Thank you !   I've switched to MultiLabelBinarizer now the dense layer is 47 for sure. But still has the high train&val accuracy but a low individual acc problem,  for example, one output prediction is this [0.01721043 0.03358928 0.00555724 0.00572211 0.00389843 0.00267933 0.00271625 0.00502731 0.00497511 0.00424288 ... 0.00513987 0.00492555 0.0064611  0.00327547 0.01186842 0.00186257 0.00474926 0.00405478 0.00668807 0.0043529  0.0052127  0.00720646]